# Triggering different Jenkins pipelines based on git commits, pull requests, and merges

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm looking at triggering different Jenkins pipelines depending on what has occurred in Github. I want one set of pipelines to occur on a git commit and another set on a pull request and another set on a merge.

Currently I have a Jenkinsfile that runs these builds and tests on every commit. Is there a way to break these up into separate pipelines/builds that are ran on specific git behavior? I'm not finding too much in the way of documentation for this. Seems to be an all or nothing sort of thing.

Comment: You could also split up your logic into functions which are executed depending on the git branch/repo. This works better when all pipelines would share a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple webhooks which can point to the different pipeline. In each webhook you can define the actions which will trigger the pipeline.

Hope it may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case but rather than have different pipelines, I have one pipeline with a number of conditional stages. Part of the reason I went with this approach was because a lot of the stages could be resued and having them in one pipeline made that simpler. For example, I always want to do a build and run unit tests, but I only want to run static code analysis on PRs and merges.

My solution:

First I have a stage that determines what happened in git (commit, PR, merge, ...) and which stages I need.

```
            stage('Compute Stages'){
                steps { script {
                   Set stages = computeStages(env.GIT_BRANCH, env.CHANGE_ID, env.CHANGE_TARGET,...)
            }}}
```

Then for my stages I just have conditions to see if it should run:

```
            stage('Some Stage') {
                when {
                    beforeAgent true
                    expression {return (stages.contains(STAGES.SOME_STAGE))}
                }
                steps {script {
                        do stage stuff
               }}}
```

p.s. note that the snippets above will not work as-is via copy-and-paste, they are meant to describe the overall idea